# Bagging for sparse survey data regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, survey, aggregation, bagging

A colleague came to me with an idea for training a regression model from a very large but sparse survey data set.

In this data set, many variables are available but most respondents only answered a few.

She proposes to repeatedly select (with replacement) a few thousand survey responses and compute averages for each variable for the selected responses (ignoring null values). Then, she plans to use all of these averages to train a multiple linear regression model (using certain variables are the independent variables with the rest as dependent).

This idea seems somewhat unorthodox to me but given its simplicity, I imagine that it has been considered before. Is there a name for this approach? Is this a sound methodology? What are the pitfalls? When should I use it/not use it?

Comment: Among the very many problematic aspects of this *ad hoc* procedure, its reliance on the Ecological Fallacy stands out.